# Как сделать ограничение на неизвестных пользователей aiogram

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

есть список id "белых пользователей", как на аиограме сделать проверку и, если id не белый то не допускать его до бота

Comment: Если сможете найти ответ на эти вопросы, решите свой вопрос: 1) как в aiogram при получении сообщения вытащить id юзера? (подсказка `from_user.id`) 2) как в питоне проверить наличие значения в списке?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно проверить наличие id пользователя в списке "белых" пользователей (в примере - `white_users`) с помощью `if message.from_user.id in white_users`, и завершать исполнение функции, если условие не выполняется.

Пример:

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
async def <название функции>(message: types.Message):
  if message.from_user.id not in white_users:
    return
  # Ваш код функции
```